# Rhythmbox doesn't find Sansa Clip+

Tags: rhythmbox, sansa-clip

I am currently trying to get Rhythmbox to recognized my Sansa Clip+, which used to work in previous versions. I am now on a fresh Xubuntu install and it no longer recognizes the player. However running Rhythmbox with `rhythmbox -d` and then manually mounting the players shows that the player is actually detected properly, it just never shows up in the GUI. The last line, `Unhandled media` hints at something being wrong, but what?

```
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [rhythmdb_mount_added_cb] rhythmdb-monitor.c:430: volume file:///media/mp3 mounted
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [rhythmdb_read_enter] rhythmdb.c:1229: counter: 1
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [rhythmdb_query_internal] rhythmdb.c:4016: doing query
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [do_query_recurse] rhythmdb-tree.c:2304: doing recursive query, 1 conjunctions
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [rhythmdb_query_internal] rhythmdb.c:4022: completed
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [rhythmdb_mount_added_cb] rhythmdb-monitor.c:444: 0 mounted entries to process
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [dump_volume_identifiers] rb-removable-media-manager.c:627: unix-device = /dev/sde
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [dump_volume_identifiers] rb-removable-media-manager.c:627: uuid = 0123-4567
found device path /dev/sde for mount /media/mp3
found ID_MEDIA_PLAYER tag sandisk_sansa-clip-plus for device /dev/sde
device information (system database)
information read from system device database
model: Sansa_Clip+_4GB
vendor: SanDisk
filesystem uuid: 0123-4567
drive type: (none)
requires eject: true
access protocols:
    storage
output formats:
    audio/mpeg
    audio/x-ms-wma
    audio/audible
    application/ogg
    audio/ogg
    audio/flac
    audio/x-wav
    audio/x-pn-audibleaudio
input formats:
    audio/x-wav
playlist formats:
    audio/x-mpegurl
playlist path: 
audio folders:
    MUSIC/
    PODCAST/
    PODCASTS/
    RECORD/FM/
    RECORD/VOICE/
    AUDIBLE/
    AUDIOBOOKS/
folder depth: -1
/media/mp3 is already a mount point
override file /media/mp3/.is_audio_player not found on mount /media/mp3
(03:01:06) [0x9a77068] [rb_removable_media_manager_add_mount] rb-removable-media-manager.c:748: Unhandled media
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
apt-get install gnome
```

Apparently one of the many packages that that pulls is needed to fix the issue.